# How can we know the row position that contain specific words?

Tags: php

I have some file, **month.txt** which contains:

```
First month is January
Second month is February
And third is March
Then April
And then May
And June
```

How can i get the number of line if i search specific word using PHP?

Example:
I search word of **April**, then output is **April in line number of 3**.

Comment: Hi Junianto, can you please provide what you have tried so far, and show the error of your attempt? Otherwise, we cannot answer a question about "How to know the row".

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file into an array `file`, search for the word `preg_grep` and get the index `key` for that line.  If you want it case-insensitive use the `i` modifier `'/April/i'`:

```
echo key(preg_grep('/April/', file('/path/to/month.txt')));
```